# Break up app engine cron jobs into smaller chunks?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a cron job which parses a # of RSS feeds. It turns out it takes too long so I'm getting a HardDeadlineExceededError. I tried just creating two cron jobs, one which parses the even feeds, one which parses the odd feeds, I still get the error.

What's the best way to break up this work so it fits within a 30 second window?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html) -- a task can perform any number N of sub-tasks of your choice, making sure to get close but not *too* close to the hard-deadline, then it spawns another task to continue where the spawner left off.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the number of jobs to decrease the number of feeds per job. Not just two segments (odd and even), but more (feed number MOD x) until it fits into the window.

If this does not work (too many cron jobs), take a look at Task Queues. This way the cron job could push out the work into the queue, maybe one task per feed.

Comment: So if I have say 12 cron jobs all set to run every 15 minutes, would the fact they're all running at the same time be a problem?

Comment: Maybe. There is (or at least there was) a maximum number of server processes you could get at the same time. This limit will be higher for high-traffic site, but heavy cron jobs on small-traffic sites might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a simple datastore object that tracks what RSS feed I parsed last. I parse one RSS feed and increment the variable every time the cron job runs.